# $K$-automorphisms and Galois actions

Tags: galois-theory

We consider a field $K$ and an irreducible polynomial $f \in K[x]$.
I have the following definition: a $K$-automorphism is a rational fraction $A \in K(x)$, such that for some rational fraction $D(x) \in K(x)$, we have $f(A(x)) = D(x)f(x)$.

Note that $K(x)$ is the field of rational functions in $x$.
My questions are:

1) Is a $K$-automorphism a Galois action, i.e., an action of the Galois group of $f$ on $K$ ? or can there be some actions that are not of this form ?

2) Why are $A, D$ rational fractions ?

3) Could I defined the order of a Galois action?

Any links to litterature concerning the subject or details about this definition are more than welcome !

Comment: Can you define your terms?  I assume $K$ is a field, what is $f$ supposed to be?  Is $K(x)$ the field of fractions of the polynomial ring over $K$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot! I will update right away

Comment: Something looks wrong here. Ordinarily, an automorphism is not an element of any field. Did you get this definition out of some source?